# Unable to Use glyphicons in bootstrap3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i downloaded bootstrap 3 and now i am trying to use glyphicon (chevron-left and right) icons in html but they are not working. i have confirmed that their urls are specified correctly in the @font-face atrribute in the bootstrap.css file. I have tried this below but it doesn't work.Instead, it shows Eo79 in place of the glyphicon image.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
```

Comment: Try using the Bootstrap CDN:
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the problem was with firefox. So i toggled the security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy in about:config url. But it worked fine in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the `font` folder you get with Bootstrap?  It should be located in the same directory as the `CSS` folder.

Comment: No..i did not move it.